# how to change array elements after initialization

Tags: c++, arrays, initialization

very noob question, I apologize in advance.

I have an declared and initialized an array X. I use that array, later in the code I want X to take on new values.

```
double X[2] = { 0.85, 0.15 };
//some code using X[]

X = { 0.84, 0.16 }; //--> this gives "error: assigning to an array from an initializer list"
//more code using X[]

X[] = { 0.84, 0.16 }; //--> this gives "error: expected primary-expression before ‘]’ token"
//more code using X[]
```

what is the correct way to do this?

Comment: How about `X[0]=1` and `X[1]=2`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not possible, but you can use `std::array<double, 2>`. Since `X` will be an object, your notation will be valid. Well... almost. You'll have to write it like `X = {{0.84, 0.16}};` (one more pair of braces).

Answer (score 0):

You can't assign a new value to an array, you need to assign the elements individually.

```
X[0] = 0.84;
X[1] = 0.16;
```

Answer (score 0):

Initializer lists are just usable during initialization.

You can use **any one of the below array** to init an array with name `X`

```
double X[ ] = { 0.85, 0.15 }; // initialize array X with 2 values 

double X[2] = { 0.85, 0.15 }; // initialize array X with 2 values with size
```

If you badly want to declare in the above manner you can do it this way.

```
std::array<double, 2> X;
X = {0.64,0.16};
```